# How can I set custom colors on stroke amchart js library?

Tags: javascript, svg, amcharts

I'm using [AmCharts Javascript Library](http://www.amcharts.com/) to present chart on HTML with SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics). The problems are default stroke colors!
I want use my own colors. Is there any way to set the stroke colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the color by graph by using the `lineColor` property.

ex.

```
graph = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
graph.linecolor = "#FF0000";
```

Comment: Except it's "lineColor" not "linecolor"

Answer (score 1):

Go to code that start AmChart. After new `AmCharts.AmSerialChart()` add the line:

```
chart.colors = "#000000 #B0DE09 #990000 #0D8ECF #2A0CD0 #CD0D74 #CC0000 #00CC00 #0000CC #DDDDDD #999999 #333333 #990000".split(' ');
```

Each RGB code is a color of a chart from left to right!